# How can i do office interop on Click to Run installations?

Tags: .net, interop, ms-office, office-interop, office-2013

I have a .net application that heavily interops (today with excel, tommorrow with the whole office suite) with office and i'm getting pretty worried about 2013 being CTR only (except for volume licenses).

I followed the Google sync fiasco with 2013 & keep reading it requires a whole re architecturing to support CTR install, but i'm "very willing" to do it, i can't seem to find any information on this however so does anyone know how to actually interop with CTR office 2010 / 2013?

I'm not looking for ways to get the non CTR version, i want to program in a way that i can natively support both and not push the burden on my customers to switch version (which they won't anyway). I'm also not programming add ins (hosted Inside apps) but external .net apps that need to be able to interop with the office suite like i always did so far using excel interop (ability to retrieve running instance & recycle them or start new instances and access everything the interop API exposes).

So since i'm willing to restart my project from scratch but CANNOT impose specific office installation (both the media & non default options) on my customers, what is the appropriate way to interop with office 2013 CTR? Will that appropriate way also work with non CTR versions or do i need 2 code paths? Any help is most welcome as, if i don't find a solution to this, my program is as good as dead.

Comment: By CTR, I presume you're referring to "Click-to-Run"?  Are there documented issues with Interop? Is there a different way of interfacing to CTR-installed version of Office?

Comment: Yes i mean click to run, and as far as i understand it CTR doesn't run the same way (runs in a virtualized environment). I couldn't find any documentation on interoperating with the CTR versions and 2013 is only available as CTR for non volume licensees with no installation options (so no interop assemblies installed). I also don't think it's as simple as installing the PIA as everywhere Google sync was mentioned as breaking Google indicated support for CTR office 2013 required a full re architecturing of Google sync, & i can't find any information on what is needed at all.

Comment: Perhaps your worries are undue?  I don't think MS would cease rich support for something as fundamental as office interop, even if their office execution environment model is to change.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with interop.word in a .net application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317829/problem-with-interop-word-in-a-net-application)

Comment: @PaulSweatte no the questions are completely unrelated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem my worries were for nothing, interop works just fine with CTR installations and the issue Google faced with CTR and sync is probably unrelated to interop